# extract specific data from numpy ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

New to pandas any help is appreciated

[image: Snapshot of the dataset]

```
def csv_reader(fileName):
    reqcols=['_id__$oid','payload','channel']
    io = pd.read_csv(fileName,sep=",",usecols=reqcols)
    print(io['payload'].values)
    return io
```

Output row of io['payload']:

```
{
    "destination_ip": "172.31.14.66",
    "date": "2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861",
    "classification": "Potentially Bad Traffic",
    "proto": "UDP",
    "source_ip": "172.31.0.2",
    "priority": "`2",
    "header": "1:2003195:5",
    "signature": "ET POLICY Unusual number of DNS No Such Name Responses ",
    "source_port": "53",
    "destination_port": "34638",
    "sensor": "5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"
}
```

I am trying to extract specific data from the ndarray object. What is the method that can be used to extract from the dataframe

```
"destination_ip": "172.31.13.124",
"proto": "ICMP",
"source_ip": "201.158.32.1",
"date": "2014-09-28T14:49:43.391463",
"sensor": "139cfdf2-471e-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"
```

Comment: Show us a sample of your input data.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Please check the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first convert `string` reperesentation of `dicts` to `dictionaries` in each row by `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval` in column `payload`, then create new `DataFrame` by constructor, filter columns by subset, and if necessary add original columns by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
d = {'_id__$oid': ['542f8', '542f8', '542f8'], 'channel': ['snort_alert', 'snort_alert', 'snort_alert'], 'payload': ['{"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861","classification":"Potentially Bad Traffic","proto":"UDP","source_ip":"172.31.0.2","priority":"2","header":"1:2003195:5","signature":"ET POLICY Unusual number of DNS No Such Name Responses ","source_port":"53","destination_port":"34638","sensor":"5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"}', '{"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861","classification":"Potentially Bad Traffic","proto":"UDP","source_ip":"172.31.0.2","priority":"2","header":"1:2003195:5","signature":"ET POLICY Unusual number of DNS No Such Name Responses ","source_port":"53","destination_port":"34638","sensor":"5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"}', '{"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861","classification":"Potentially Bad Traffic","proto":"UDP","source_ip":"172.31.0.2","priority":"2","header":"1:2003195:5","signature":"ET POLICY Unusual number of DNS No Such Name Responses ","source_port":"53","destination_port":"34638","sensor":"5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"}']}
reqcols=['_id__$oid','payload','channel']
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
  _id__$oid      channel                                            payload
0     542f8  snort_alert  {"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014...
1     542f8  snort_alert  {"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014...
2     542f8  snort_alert  {"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014...
```

---

```
import json
import ast
df.payload = df.payload.apply(json.loads)
#another slowier solution
#df.payload = df.payload.apply(ast.literal_eval)

required = ["destination_ip", "proto", "source_ip", "date", "sensor"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.payload.values.tolist())[required]
print (df1)
  destination_ip proto   source_ip                        date  \
0   172.31.14.66   UDP  172.31.0.2  2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861   
1   172.31.14.66   UDP  172.31.0.2  2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861   
2   172.31.14.66   UDP  172.31.0.2  2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861   

                                 sensor  
0  5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e  
1  5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e  
2  5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e  

df2 = pd.concat([df[['_id__$oid','channel']], df1], axis=1)
print (df2)
  _id__$oid      channel destination_ip proto   source_ip  \
0     542f8  snort_alert   172.31.14.66   UDP  172.31.0.2   
1     542f8  snort_alert   172.31.14.66   UDP  172.31.0.2   
2     542f8  snort_alert   172.31.14.66   UDP  172.31.0.2   

                         date                                sensor  
0  2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861  5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e  
1  2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861  5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e  
2  2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861  5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e
```

**Timings**:

```
#[30000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

In [38]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.payload.apply(json.loads).values.tolist())[required]
1 loop, best of 3: 379 ms per loop

In [39]: %timeit pd.read_json('[{}]'.format(df.payload.str.cat(sep=',')))[required]
1 loop, best of 3: 528 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.payload.apply(ast.literal_eval).values.tolist())[required]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.98 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @jezrael's sample `df`

```
d = {'_id__$oid': ['542f8', '542f8', '542f8'], 'channel': ['snort_alert', 'snort_alert', 'snort_alert'], 'payload': ['{"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861","classification":"Potentially Bad Traffic","proto":"UDP","source_ip":"172.31.0.2","priority":"2","header":"1:2003195:5","signature":"ET POLICY Unusual number of DNS No Such Name Responses ","source_port":"53","destination_port":"34638","sensor":"5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"}', '{"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861","classification":"Potentially Bad Traffic","proto":"UDP","source_ip":"172.31.0.2","priority":"2","header":"1:2003195:5","signature":"ET POLICY Unusual number of DNS No Such Name Responses ","source_port":"53","destination_port":"34638","sensor":"5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"}', '{"destination_ip":"172.31.14.66","date": "2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861","classification":"Potentially Bad Traffic","proto":"UDP","source_ip":"172.31.0.2","priority":"2","header":"1:2003195:5","signature":"ET POLICY Unusual number of DNS No Such Name Responses ","source_port":"53","destination_port":"34638","sensor":"5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"}']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

***solution***

- Smash all `payload`s together with a vecorized `str.cat`
- Parse the whole thing at once with `pd.read_json`

---

```
cols = 'destination_ip proto source_ip date sensor'.split()
df.drop(
    'payload', 1
).join(
    pd.read_json('[{}]'.format(df.payload.str.cat(sep=',')))[cols]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I think your solution is faster, but not.

Comment: over 3 rows?  Or more?

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: @jezrael that's good information!  I'm surprised.  But I'm glad you tested it.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straight forward to access columns in pandas.  Simply pass a list of the columns you need:

**Code:**

```
columns = ["destination_ip", "proto", "source_ip", "date", "sensor"]
extracted_data = df[columns]
```

**Test Code:**

```
data = {
    "destination_ip": "172.31.14.66",
    "date": "2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861",
    "classification": "Potentially Bad Traffic",
    "proto": "UDP",
    "source_ip": "172.31.0.2",
    "priority": "`2",
    "header": "1:2003195:5",
    "signature": "ET POLICY Unusual number of DNS No Such Name Responses ",
    "source_port": "53",
    "destination_port": "34638",
    "sensor": "5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e"
}
df = pd.DataFrame([data, data])

columns = ["destination_ip", "proto", "source_ip", "date", "sensor"]
print(df[columns])
```

**Results:**

```
  destination_ip proto   source_ip                        date  \
0   172.31.14.66   UDP  172.31.0.2  2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861   
1   172.31.14.66   UDP  172.31.0.2  2014-10-19T01:32:36.669861   

                                 sensor  
0  5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e  
1  5cda4a12-4730-11e4-9ee4-0a0b6e7c3e9e
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `payload` is a column of your CSV input data, and it is a JSON string.  So you first can `read_csv()` as you have done to parse the overall file, but the you need to parse each JSON object inside.  Let's use this example data:

```
payload = pd.Series(['{"a":1, "b":2}', '{"b":4, "c":5}'])
```

Now make a single JSON string:

```
json = ','.join(payload).join('[]')
```

Which gives:

```
'[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"b":4, "c":5}]'
```

Then parse it:

```
pd.read_json(json)
```

To get:

```
     a  b    c
0  1.0  2  NaN
1  NaN  4  5.0
```